# UMI.cms статусы заказов

Tags: umi

Как в Umi.CMS удалить статусы заказов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти страницу со списком всех статусов заказов, нужно:

1. Открыть в админке любой заказ
2. Найти поле "Статус заказа"
3. Под полем должна быть ссылка "Редактировать элементы справочника"
4. По клику на ссылку откроется нужная страница

[image: Скриншот админки]